# Two factor authentication using time base key generator on smartphones

Tags: .net, android, iphone, authentication

I recently enabled [two factor authentication for my Google account](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/advanced-sign-in-security-for-your.html). One of the ways of getting the second factor (the key that I have) is to install an Android app on my phone that displays a key for a short duration of time.

What does it take to create a web server solution paired with a smartphone solution?

I am using Windows and .NET on the server side and would be interested in both Android and iPhone apps. Are there existing libraries out there or do I need to start from scratch? Where is some starting documentation and explanations of the techniques used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog post, [Using Google Authenticator For Your Website](http://www.brool.com/index.php/using-google-authenticator-for-your-website), talks about using google authenticator in your own website.

> The Google code provides a command line program that can generate secret keys as well as a PAM module, but it turns out to be very little code to authenticate a TOTP, thereby providing two-factor authentication to your website very easily.

Otherwise take a look at [OATH](http://www.openauthentication.org/) which is an open OTP solution, there are a number of libraries and hardware solutions supporting this technology.

- [Yubikey](http://www.yubico.com/oath-yubikey)
- [OATH based OTP generation](http://obovweb.appspot.com/)

["How do I generate One time passwords (OTP / HOTP)?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169253/how-do-i-generate-one-time-passwords-otp-hotp) might provide some insight as well.

I've also provided a client-only library for the yubikey on bitbucket. [The library implements the client-side api for the hardware yubikey](https://bitbucket.org/tvjames/yubikey/wiki/Home).

Comment: A lot of good information here.  I am taking a look at the "GoogleAuthenticator for your Website" link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look up cryptographic hash functions.  The more popular ones, like SHA-1, should have libraries in almost every language. For example, android has the java.security.MessageDigest class.  You would hash the current date and time down to the minute, together with a long string unique to the individual, then modify the output somehow to make it reasonable to type into a login dialog.